# How to disable battery saving when battery level is below 15%?

Tags: root-access, 4.4-kitkat, settings, battery, charging

I used an old tablet to operate a smart home. In order to work continuously, I took the battery out of it and connected it to a 4V power source, which works continuously. Based on the measured battery resistance between GND and BSI, I soldered a 10k resistor. After this treatment, the tablet works properly, only despite the constant voltage level, the battery level drops after a few hours to 1%. I would not have a problem with it if the battery saving function did not limit the capabilities of the device. Is there any way to turn it off? The tablet has root access.

Comment: Any particular reason why you could not go ahead with keeping the device connected to a charger all the time? Device is old, so battery degradation due to constant charging should not have been an issue. Anyhow, which Android device is it? Do you have root access? What battery saving functions are you talking about? I don't think proper battery saver (the way it exists in newer Androids) existed back in Android 4.

Comment: If you leave the device connected to a charger with a li-ion battery, the battery will overcharge over time and begin to swell. Due to the fact that this device is supposed to work continuously all year round when hanging on the wall, I took the battery out of it for safety. In addition, I led out the wires on the back of the housing, so the usb socket is empty and no visible plugs or wires stick out. The device is a Samsung Galaxy Note 10.1 and has root access. Features that reduce battery consumption include, for example, the inability to adjust the backlight or slowing the processor clock.

Comment: Ah, yes. Safety issue is a big one. Thanks for clarifying that.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to mock the battery level to 100% by using ADB by the following command:

```
adb shell dumpsys battery set level 100
```

The battery level should then stay at 100%.